# Construct a polynomial over $k$ whose zero set is $(0,\ldots,0).$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $K$ is a field which is not algebraically closed. Given any natural number $n$ how can I construct a  polynomial in $n$ variables whose zero set in $K^n$ is $(0,\ldots,0) (n-tuple).$

Give me some hint. Will characteristic play a role here ?

Comment: Does $x^2(x^2+1)+y^2(y^2+1)$ work for $n=2$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Mathematician42 : your polynomial has empty zero set over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @ Mathematician 42: even simpler expression will work over $\mathbb{R}.$ Can you generalize it ?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2236772/228113) to a very similar question contains some techniques.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: No, $x=0$ and $y=0$ is a zero. We don't really need the $x^2+1$, just take $\sum_i X_i^2$

Comment: @Mathematician42 : yes sorry I am definitely too tired for comment these times ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible monic polynomial of degree $d\geq 2$. Let $F(x_0,x_1)$ be the homogenization so that $f(x)=F(x,1)$. Clearly, for $n=2$, this $F$ works. Let me do this for $n=3$ for ease of notation and the rest should be clear. Consider $F(F(x_0,x_1), x_2^d)$. Then, this is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d^2$ and easy to check that the only zero of this over the base field is $(0,0,0)$ as follows. If $F(F(a,b),c^d)=0$, then we get putting $F(a,b)=p$, $F(p,c^d)=0$. By the two variable case, we must have $p=0, c=0$. But, $0=p=F(a,b)$ again by two variable case implies $a=b=0$.

Comment: Will it help to express an affine algebraic set over an non algebraically closed field as a zero set of a single polynomial ?

Comment: An affine algebraic set (at least in algebraic geometry) is not just the points defined over the given field. So, the answer to your question is no unless you explain  help for what?