# Can a variety "of dimension $\geqslant 1$" be finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, and $V\subset K^n$ the zero-set of $n-1$ polynomials over $K$ in $n$ variables.

**Question 1.** If $V$ is non-empty, can it be finite?

**Question 2.** What if $K$ is not algebraically closed and $V$ non-empty?

Edit. If $n=2$, then either the polynomial $p$ defining $V$ is in one variable $x$ and $V$ projects onto $K$ via the other coordinate, or the two coordinates appear in $V$, and then $V$ projects onto a cofinite subset of $K$ via either coordinates.

Comment: The title doesn't quite match the question, in my opinion. What definition of "dimension" are you considering?

Comment: I added brackets. That is the idea of the Zariski dimension though, the number of equations needed to define the variety. Don't you think? But I can change the title again if you insist.

Comment: 2) There's $x_1^2+x_2^2$ for $\Bbb R^2$. And [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2236772/228113).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$V$ can be finite, since it can be empty.  For instance, one of your polynomials could be $1$.  If $V$ is nonempty and $K$ is algebraically closed, though, it must be infinite.  This follows from basic dimension theory (essentially Krull's principal ideal theorem): each defining polynomial decreases the local dimension at any point by at most $1$, so $V$ has positive dimension at each of its points, whereas a finite set has dimension $0$ at each point. (If you're not familiar with these results, this is really a longer story than I can tell in a brief answer here, but you should be able to find this fact in some form in any introductory algebraic geometry text.)

If $K$ is not algebraically closed, then all bets are off.  For instance, for $K=\mathbb{R}$, the single point $\{(0,0)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is the vanishing set of the polynomial $x^2+y^2$.  In fact, *every* finite subset of $K^n$ is the vanishing set of a single polynomial if $K$ is not algebraically closed (see [Affine variety over a field which is not algebraically closed can be written as the zero set of a single polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642593/affine-variety-over-a-field-which-is-not-algebraically-closed-can-be-written-as)).

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would add that if you consider varieties as schemes of finite type over a field (which is a pretty common thing to do), fields that are not algebraically closed still give the same result. So that part depends on what OP's definition of "variety" is.

Comment: Well, they said explicitly that they are considering $V$ as a subset of $K^n$.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I missed that.